# Whats the difference between interpretation and evaluation in racket/scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, terminology

At first glance they seem to be very similar. Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpretation is an algorithmic procedure of implementing evaluation.  Evaluation is related to interpretation in computation in the same way as the entailment is related to inference in logic (a way of implementing entailment can be seen in prolog that implements a kind of inference algorithm).  While entailment is a mathematical way of implementing logical deduction, when you want to implement this deduction on a computer you use an inference algorithm.

Evaluation is the name of the mathematical process of providing an answer to a computation.

Interpretation is a way of implementing the evaluation (an interpreter is a function that implements the mathematical `eval` function).

Compilation is the same as interpretation (it does almost the same steps that an interpreter does) but it precomputes static results about the code and it generates a bytecode for a virtual machine ([SECD machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECD_machine) for scheme, [WAM machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Abstract_Machine) for prolog, etc).  The virtual machine is another way of implementing evaluation, etc.

There are other way of implementing the evaluation.  The [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) is a way (and the simplest one, although it covers all the main concepts).

Another way to implement evaluation is via [redex](https://redex.racket-lang.org/).

To find out more, you can look over the courses of type SICP taught in universities.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation implies evaluation, but not all evaluation has to be interpretation.

An interpreter is a function or program that takes a program as input and evaluates it. Interpretation usually means "evaluation with an interpreter."

On the other hand evaluation doesn't always mean interpretation. Evaluation can happen by executing a compiled program, or by running with a JIT-compiler, or by iterating small-step reductions, or any other method you can think of in addition to interpretation.

Comment: But isn't executing a compiled program an interpretation as well? (i.e., CPU is an interpreter for executable binaries).

Comment: I guess, but as a programmer any interpreters at that low level are "abstracted away" so it's invisible or doesn't matter

Comment: what does "by iterating small-step reductions" mean? can you give an example?

Comment: One example of small-step reductions is the DrRacket Stepper for the *SL languages, Beginning Student Language through Intermediate Student Language with Lambda. It's not meant to just produce the "answer", but to show intermediate steps inside the evaluation, so the steps can be understood separately

Comment: Other examples of small-step reductions come from redex models mentioned in @alinsoar's answer